VSCode and debugging in venv
I have a issue in a python project in VSCode where the debugger does not stop at breakpoints and I am unable to inspect variables. The environment is Windows 10 and the project is using a venv.
I was able to get the debuigger to eventually respect a breakpoint by adding "justMyCode": false per this answer : VSCode: Why isn't debugger stopping at breakpoints?
But I am still unable to watch variable values.
I setup in my venv a simple test.py file to test this. The file contains:
print("Hello")
a= 5
b = 10
c = 11

If I break on the last line I can not see the values of a or b:

I suspect this is something to do with the venv as if I create the same file not in a venv and in a new project I can inspect the values.
Note I do think I have the correct venv selected in VSCode (polyphase):

It appears the issue is related to the venv - but I can not see how to inspect the variable values.

what debug information does your DEBUG CONSOLE output? You can check if the debug configuration of the .vscode/launch.json file is right. Then select a different interpreter to try. You can learn more about debugging configurations in document.
